# system() function doesn't execute shell command as expected

Tags: c, printf, registry, command-prompt

I have the below `command` that reads *OS* name data from registry as follows :

> `for /f "tokens=2*" %a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName ^| findstr "REG_"') do @echo %b`

```
output :    Windows 10 Enterprise
```

So now, this command does work in ***Command Prompt***, but when I use it in the `system()` function, It does not run as expected.

My `code` :

```
CHAR szCommandLine[MAX_PATH * 4] = { 0 };
StrCpyA(szCommandLine, "for /f \"tokens = 2*\" %%a in ('reg query \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\" /v ProductName ^| findstr \"REG_\"') do @echo %%b");
// print the command
printf(szCommandLine);
printf("\n");
// run the command
system(szCommandLine);
```

Output :

> `for /f "tokens=2*" %a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName ^| findstr "REG_"') do @echo %b`
>
> `%%a was unexpected at this time.`

Now I don't know exactly what happens in `system()` function that behave as wrong `command`. Actually the printed `command` in my program is precisely the same command which was running correctly in ***Command Prompt***.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181887/discussion-on-question-by-mohammadreza-panahi-system-function-doesnt-execute).

Answer (score 0):

***According [IanAbbott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5264491/ian-abbott)*** useful points :

I replaced `%a` instead of `%%a` in command parameters, Because `%%` is the same `%%` in`system()` function and this is wrong in the `command`.

`system("for /f \"tokens=2*\" %a in ('reg query \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\" /v ProductName ^| findstr \"REG_\"') do @echo %b");`